# Multi-item sort based with two different list items and reorder/reshuffle?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
li = [['m', 'z', 'asdgwergerwhwre'], 
      ['j', 'h', 'asdgasdgasdgasdgas'], 
      ['u', 'a', 'asdgasdgasdgasd'], 
      ['i', 'o', 'sdagasdgasdgdsag']]
```

I would like to sort this list alphabetically, BUT using either the first or second element in each sublist. For the above example, the desired output would be:

```
['a', 'u', 'asdgasdgasdgasd']
['h', 'j', 'asdgasdgasdgasdgas']
['i', 'o', 'sdagasdgasdgdsag']
['m', 'z', 'asdgwergerwhwre']
```

What is the best way to achieve this sort?

Comment: it is not just sort, but inner transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first step we perform some transformation (swap for first two items - if needed) and at the second aplly simple sort:

```
>>> sorted(map(lambda x: sorted(x[:2]) + [x[2]], li))
[['a', 'u', 'asdgasdgasdgasd'],
 ['h', 'j', 'asdgasdgasdgasdgas'],
 ['i', 'o', 'sdagasdgasdgdsag'],
 ['m', 'z', 'asdgwergerwhwre']]
```

Comment: Thanks. My sort is extremely large, so I ended up using your code and refactoring into a comprehension, which speed it up a good bit: `x = sorted(sorted(x[:2]) + x[2] for x in li)`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the built-in method [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) to accomplish some of this.  You would have to reverse the order of the list if you wanted to reverse the way it was printed, but that's not too difficult to do.

```
def rev(li):
    for l in li:
        l[0], l[1] = l[1], l[0]
    return li

new_list = sorted(rev(li))
```

If you wanted to sort the list based on a specific index, you can use `sorted(li, key=lambda li: li[index])`.

Comment: I don't think he simply wanted to swap l[1] and l[0], i think he wanted to sort them. your code would work if you had l[1], l[0]=min(l[1], l[0]),max(l[1], l[0])

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
li = [['m', 'z', 'asdgwergerwhwre'],
      ['j', 'h', 'asdgasdgasdgasdgas'],
      ['u', 'a', 'asdgasdgasdgasd'],
      ['i', 'o', 'sdagasdgasdgdsag']]

for _list in li:
    _list[:2]=sorted(_list[:2])

pprint.pprint(sorted(li))

>>>
[['a', 'u', 'asdgasdgasdgasd'],
 ['h', 'j', 'asdgasdgasdgasdgas'],
 ['i', 'o', 'sdagasdgasdgdsag'],
 ['m', 'z', 'asdgwergerwhwre']]
```